# datatable.js displaying all the rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, datatable

i have datatable which is displaying all the rows instead of the default 10

why?

```
>    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $('#TableList').dataTable({
>             "sEcho": 3,
>             "iDisplayLength": 10,
>             "bJQueryUI": true,
>             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
>             "bProcessing": true,
>             "bServerSide": true,
>             "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("DataList", "Home")',
>             "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
>             "aoColumns": [   { "mData": "AccountName", sDefaultContent: "", "bSortable": true },   { "sType": "Launched",
> sDefaultContent: "", "bSortable": true, "iDataSort": 4 },
>             { "mData": "InterestFreq", sDefaultContent: "", "bSortable": true },
>     { "mData": "Penalty", sDefaultContent: "", "bSortable": true }
>             ]
>         });
>     }); </script> <div class="demo_jui">
>     <table id="TableList" class="display">
>         <thead>
>             <tr>
>                 <th>Account Name</th>
>                 <th>Launched</th>
>                 <th>Interest Frequency</th>
>                 <th>Penalty</th>
>                 <th></th>
>             </tr>
>         </thead>
>         <tbody>
>         </tbody>
>     </table> </div>
```

-- MVC

```
public ActionResult DataList(){
    DCMEntities oData = new DCMEntities();
    var oList = (from w in oData.DCMAccountsDatabases orderby w.AccountName select new { w.AccountName, Launched = w.Launched , w.InterestFreq, w.Penalty }).Take(1000);
    return Json(new { iTotalRecords = oList.Count(), iTotalDisplayRecords = oList.Count(), aaData = oList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

i want the data table to display 10 rows per page , even through i have added "iDisplayLength": 10, id doesn't seems to work

Comment: Your Action should include the sEcho in the returned json

Comment: @jeroenk still the same , before i have det the cEcho inside the script

Answer (score 0):

The aaData should only be 10 long.

So it should be:

```
return Json(new { iTotalRecords = oList.Count(), iTotalDisplayRecords = oList.Count(), 
   aaData = oList.Take(10) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: the json result will have only 10 rows , how will i browse to the rest?

Comment: You have bServerSide: true, so the server should do the paging. Based on the iDisplayStart and iDisplayLength arguments. E.g. oList.Skip(iDisplayLength*iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength)